# How to Encrypt or Decrypt a File in Java?

Tags: java, cryptography

I want to encrypt and decrypt a file in java, i had read this url http://www-users.york.ac.uk/~mal503/lore/pkencryption.htm and i got two files namely public Security certificate and private security certificate file and private.pem file, i copied these files and pasted in the current directory and worte java code as follows, when i run this no encryption or decryption is performed, pls see this and tell me where i went wrong

Encrypt Code

```
File ecryptfile=new File("encrypt data");
                File publickeydata=new File("/publickey");
                File encryptmyfile=new File("/sys_data.db");
                File copycontent =new File("Copy Data");
                secure.makeKey();
                secure.saveKey(ecryptfile, publickeydata);
                secure.encrypt(encryptmyfile, copycontent);
```

Decrypt code

```
File ecryptfile=new File("encrypt data");
                File privateKeyFile=new File("/privatekey");
                File encryptmyfile=new File("/sys_data.db");
                File unencryptedFile =new File("unencryptedFile");
                try {
                                secure.loadKey(encryptmyfile, privateKeyFile);
                                secure.decrypt(encryptmyfile, unencryptedFile);
                        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

Comment: It seems you misread [usage section](http://www-users.york.ac.uk/~mal503/lore/pkencryption.htm)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You simply have muddled your files. This code works using the DER files generated from openssl as described in the article you linked:

```
    FileEncryption secure = new FileEncryption();

    // Encrypt code
    {
        File encryptFile = new File("encrypt.data");
        File publicKeyData = new File("public.der");
        File originalFile = new File("sys_data.db");
        File secureFile = new File("secure.data");

        // create AES key
        secure.makeKey();

        // save AES key using public key
        secure.saveKey(encryptFile, publicKeyData);

        // save original file securely 
        secure.encrypt(originalFile, secureFile);
    }

    // Decrypt code
    {
        File encryptFile = new File("encrypt.data");
        File privateKeyFile = new File("private.der");
        File secureFile = new File("secure.data");
        File unencryptedFile = new File("unencryptedFile");

        // load AES key
        secure.loadKey(encryptFile, privateKeyFile);

        // decrypt file
        secure.decrypt(secureFile, unencryptedFile);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I was confused, that's why, thank you very much, +1 for good answer, :)

Comment: i have got this expection java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters, i had following the above example , in that they specified they key size as 256, i was wonder whether the problem again in key generation using openssl, i had used their command, pls help me

Comment: That is a common problem when you start out. Java only allows 128 bit ciphers out-of-the-box. To use proper encryption you need to get the required policy files and install them. I have provided instructions on your ticket relating to this specific issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639990/need-help-in-encrypting-as-well-as-decrypting-a-file-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Simplest Piece of Code for encrypting a document with any Key(Here Random Key)

```
randomKey = randomKey.substring(0, 16);
        keyBytes = randomKey.getBytes();
        key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        paramSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
        in = new FileInputStream(srcFile);
        out = new FileOutputStream(encryptedFile);
        out = new CipherOutputStream(out, ecipher);
        int numRead = 0;
        while ((numRead = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, numRead);
        }
        in.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
```

Comment: "buf" variable initialization is missing