# Cryptography - Java

Tags: java, eclipse, file, encryption, output

I am a newbie to site. I have folowed this post [How to Encrypt or Decrypt a File in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632658/how-to-encrypt-or-decrypt-a-file-in-java)

and have everything functional (also following: http://www-users.york.ac.uk/~mal503/lore/pkencryption.htm and the previous stackoverflow post).

This may be a stupid question but where is the encrypted file after compiling? I cannot find it. How can I output it to either my desktop or src folder in java eclipse? I am trying to eventually turn this into an application where you can input a file at command line for encryption and then whenever you like decryption (strictly educational, for a class). Thank you for your time and help.

My Code:

```
/**
 * Utility class for encrypting/decrypting files.
 * 
 */
public class CryptoFunction {
    public static final int AES_Key_Size = 256;

    Cipher pkCipher, aesCipher;
    byte[] aesKey;
    SecretKeySpec aeskeySpec;

    /**
     * Constructor: creates ciphers
     */
    public CryptoFunction() throws GeneralSecurityException {
        // create RSA public key cipher
        pkCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        // create AES shared key cipher
        aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new AES key
     * A random AES key is generated to encrypt files.
     * A key size (AES_Key_Size) of 256 bits is standard for AES
     */
    public void makeKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        kgen.init(AES_Key_Size);
        SecretKey key = kgen.generateKey();
        aesKey = key.getEncoded();
        aeskeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(aesKey, "AES");
    }

    /**
     * Decrypts an AES key from a file using an RSA private key
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public void loadKey(File in, File privateKeyFile) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        // read private key to be used to decrypt the AES key
        byte[] encodedKey = new byte[(int)privateKeyFile.length()];
        new FileInputStream(privateKeyFile).read(encodedKey);

        // create private key
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encodedKey);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PrivateKey pk = kf.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);

        // read AES key
        pkCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pk);
        aesKey = new byte[AES_Key_Size/8];
        CipherInputStream is = new CipherInputStream(new FileInputStream(in), pkCipher);
        is.read(aesKey);
        aeskeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(aesKey, "AES");
    }

    /**
     * Encrypts the AES key to a file using an RSA public key
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public void saveKey(File out, File publicKeyFile) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        // read public key to be used to encrypt the AES key
        byte[] encodedKey = new byte[(int)publicKeyFile.length()];
        new FileInputStream(publicKeyFile).read(encodedKey);

        // create public key
        X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encodedKey);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey pk = kf.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);

        // write AES key
        pkCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pk);
        CipherOutputStream os = new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(out), pkCipher);
        os.write(aesKey);
        os.close();
    }

    /**
     * Encrypts and then copies the contents of a given file.
     */
    public void encrypt(File in, File out) throws IOException, InvalidKeyException {
        aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aeskeySpec);

        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(in);
        CipherOutputStream os = new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(out), aesCipher);

        copy(is, os);

        os.close();
    }

    /**
     * Decrypts and then copies the contents of a given file.
     */
    public void decrypt(File in, File out) throws IOException, InvalidKeyException {
        aesCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aeskeySpec);

        CipherInputStream is = new CipherInputStream(new FileInputStream(in), aesCipher);
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(out);

        copy(is, os);

        is.close();
        os.close();
    }

    /**
     * Copies a stream.
     */
    private void copy(InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
        int i;
        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
        while((i=is.read(b))!=-1) {
            os.write(b, 0, i);
            System.out.println("I is copying!");

             // read what we wrote
             for (int j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
                System.out.print("" + (char) is.read() + '\n');
             }
        }
    }


    public void encryption(){

    }

    public void decryption(){

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Begin Encyption!"); // Display the string.

        CryptoFunction secure = new CryptoFunction();

        // Encrypt code
        File encryptFile = new File("encrypt.data");
        File publicKeyData = new File("src/publickey.der");
        File originalFile = new File("src/stufftoencrypt.txt");
        File secureFile = new File("secure.data");

        // create AES key
        secure.makeKey();

        // save AES key using public key
        secure.saveKey(encryptFile, publicKeyData);

        // save original file securely
        secure.encrypt(originalFile, secureFile);


        // Decrypt code
        File encryptFile = new File("encrypt.data");
        File privateKeyFile = new File("privatekey");
        File secureFile = new File("secure.data");
        File unencryptedFile = new File("unencryptedFile");

        // load AES key
        secure.loadKey(encryptFile, privateKeyFile);

        // decrypt file
        secure.decrypt(secureFile, unencryptedFile);
        System.out.println("End Encryption!"); // Display the string.
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the code works (I didn't test it), you may need to just refresh your eclipse project. If the secure.data file is created in there, eclipse won't automatically refresh to show it. If you want to create the files in a specific location, put an absolute path into new File(...) e.g. to create in C:\temp, use:

```
File secureFile = new File("c:\\temp\\secure.data");
File unencryptedFile = new File("c:\\temp\\unencryptedFile");
```

You can check the absolute path of these files using:

```
System.out.println(unencryptedFile.getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println(secureFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: The refresh was correct, but I have asecond issue. Now that I have the secure.data file in my src (encrypted) and I get the unencrypted file in src folder (decrypted) the decrypted file is not decrypted. Any ideas?